# How run multi jvm test in sbt?

Tags: java, testing, jvm, sbt

Here is [akka sharding example](https://github.com/nraychaudhuri/akka-sharding-example.git). I am tying to run one multi jvm test `JobStreamRenderSpec` from command line like `sbt clean test-only sharding.example.JobStreamRenderSpec` and get an error -

```
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: sharding
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: sharding (similar: showTiming)
[error] sharding.example.JobStreamRenderSpec
[error]
```

But when I run `sbt clean test` build compile and all tests runs.

What I do wring or sbt can not run multi-jvm tests?

Answer (score 2):

```
sbt "multi-jvm:testOnly sharding.example.JobStreamRenderSpec"
```

Comment: Please explain the flags and how you found them. This way people will understand why your answer works, and not just that it does.

Comment: The quotes are needed so SBT parses the two strings as one command, which is what it is. Without the quotes it would parse it as two separate commands and then the first is missing its required argument while the second one is not a recognized command.